# TYPO3: Backend Toolbar User-Settings gone after Update to TYPO3 v9.5.19 from v8.7

Tags: typo3, toolbar, typo3-9.x

We upgraded a TYPO3 installation from 8.7.x to 9.5.19.
Afterwards, the User-Icon dopdown in the top toolbar is missing. (see screenshots)

We found out that the toolbar is generated in this class:
/typo3/sysext/backend/Classes/Backend/ToolbarItems/UserToolbarItem.php

We see that there have been lots of changes here since v7.6 but don't know where to go from there.
Is there a configuration file, where the items in the top bar are noted?

Additional information: we are working with the typo3-themes extension and have worked with our own theme before the update. During the update we switched to the bootstrap4 + bootstrap4-child theme - would this be a starting place for further investigations?

Before upgrade:
[image: Before - User Dropdown working]

After upgrade:
[image: After, Icon/settings missing]

Comment: Did you clear all caches? Did you try a different browser to make sure it's not a local caching issue? Do you have any 3rd party extensions installed which might want to extend the toolbar? Did you check log the in the TYPO3 backend and var/logs/ for error messages?

Comment: Thanks @peterkraume! You led me on the right track - it was the typo3_console extension. as soon as i deactivated it, the user button reappeared. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution for us was to disabling the "belog" extension.

Comment: Hello Stephan, thanks a lot! I have never heard of that extension and at first thought, it was a typo (not 3). After looking in the extensions i found and disabled it - and the user-dropdown appeared!

I will keep an eye on it.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE:** **It seems like this was at least not the root of the problems. After reactivating typo3_console the user-icon was still visible. So it looks like we have further investigating to do.**

**Update (2 Days later):**
**We can't reproduce the error. My best guess for now is, that deactivating the extension "repaired" a corrupt configuration file which had caused the disappearing of the user settings icon. After a lot of researching i have not found anybody with a similar problem so this might be an edge case. I wish i could offer more insight to this.**

Thanks to Peter Kraume's basic suggestions i found the answer: after i deactivated the extension typo3_console it immediately worked!

Just for the record, here are the other steps we tried:

BE  (via top bar)

- Flush frontend caches
- Flush all caches

BE Admin Tools ("Maintenance")

- Flush TYPO3 and PHP Cache
- Remove Temporary Assets

Logs

- BE System log shows no current errors
- Shared Hosting, /var/ contains no logs, /logs/ contains ftp and access logs

Hosting Provider Backend

- Cleared OPcache
- Created a new Admin-User, logged in, same behaviour
- Tried on two different PCs
- Primarily tested on Firefox 77.01, checked with Chrome 83.0.4103.116

Extensions:

- was not sure, which extensions might manipulate the topbar - deactivated typo3-console, because i remembered seeing some error during the upgrade process. My feeling was more like: i don't need this right now, so i could as well deactivate it.  1 second later, the user drop-down reappeared. Unbelievable! Thanks for reminding me of the basic stuff - like turning off things!

Comment: Thx for sharing your approach to isolate the problem. But I'm curious why why just this extension is responsible for the error. EXT:typo3_console has nothing to do with the backend interface. It's solely a CLI tool. Is your error reproducible once you install the extension again? By the way, is your installation composer based or "classic"?

Comment: Thanks for asking again - there seems to be something else at work: when i checked back, the user-icon was "gone" again. After clicking other modules like protocol and extensions, it reappeared again. To test a possible connection to typo3_console i reactivated it in the extension manager - and the user menu is still present. Now i am confused. Maybe the deactivation of an extension via the extension manager caused something to repair a corrupt config file, like LocalConfiguration.php or PackageStates.php? btw. it is a classic install. Will investigate further. any ideas right now?

Comment: Things got even more weird - the icon disappeared again a short while after that. We found no way how to get it back.

Only today, @Stephan-Boiting found the answer (see accepted answer) which worked for us too!

Answer (score 1):

We just had the same problem after upgrade from TYPO3 8 to 9. I have compared the working BE-User with the non-working BE user. They differ in given Language. Working BE-User has lang=''. Non-Working BE-User lang='de'. After switching the working BE-User to lang de, too, the UserToolbar is gone. I have updated the languages in Maintenance-Module and now everything works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I could solve it on all systems with:
Install-Tool > Maintenance > Manage Language Packs > Download the files again.

Comment: Thanks Kobi! We had the problem on another system and could solve it with the help of your answer!